# How many permutations are there of $1, \ldots ,8$ in which none of the patterns 12, 34, 56, 78 appear?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

I had thought this was a fairly simple Inclusion/Exclusion problem, but I noticed that my answer doesn't match the back of the book. Here is my thought process:

Let S denote the set of all permutations of $1,\ldots ,8$. Then $\#S = 8!$.

We want to exclude the following properties:

$P(1)$: 12 occurs

$P(2)$: 34 occurs

$P(3)$: 56 occurs

$P(4)$: 78 occurs

So then $N(i)=7!$, $1 \leq i \leq 4$, $i \in \mathbb{N}$ because we can "combine" the 2-digit numbers into 1 and then find the number of permutations for a length 7 string.

$P(1,2)$: 12 and 34 occur

... and so on (6 times)

So $N(i,j) = 5!$ because we combine 4 of the numbers and treat it as one number in a string of length 5 ([1234] 5 6 7 8 would be an arrangement).

However, I stopped here because my book says that $N(i,j)=6!$, and I cant seem to figure out why. In addition, it says $N(i,j,k) = 5!$, but I would think it would be $3!$. What am I missing?

Comment: I think I just figured it out. We don't combine 1234 altogether. 12 and 34 become individual elements in a length 6 string. Should I delete this post?

Comment: You may edit the post or answer your own question. It might help some other people looking at your post. If you want to delete it then sure you can do that as well.

Comment: My answer is 24024. Perhaps that is useful.